# Reference for the Gateaux gradient of a functional on a Hilbert manifold

Tags: manifolds, hilbert-spaces, vector-analysis, gateaux-derivative

The [entry for Gâteaux gradient](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_gradient) in the Encyclopedia of Mathematics wiki  reads:

> Gâteaux gradient of a functional $f$ at a point $x_0$ of a Hilbert space $H$.
> The vector in $H$ equal to the Gâteaux derivative $f_G'(x_0)$ of $f$ at $x_0$. In other words, the Gâteaux gradient is defined by the formula
> $$f(x_0+h) - f(x_0) = f(x_0) + (f_G'(x_0),h) + \epsilon(h),$$
> where $\epsilon(th)\rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow 0$. In an $n$-dimensional Euclidean space the Gâteaux gradient $f_G'(x0)$ is the vector with coordinates
> $$\left(\frac{\partial f(x_0)}{\partial x_1},\ldots,\frac{\partial f(x_0)}{\partial x_n}\right),$$
> and is simply known as the gradient. The concept of the Gâteaux gradient may be extended to the case when $X$ is a Riemannian manifold (finite-dimensional) or an infinite-dimensional Hilbert manifold and $f$ is a smooth real function on $X$. The growth of $f$ in the direction of its Gâteaux gradient is larger than in any other direction passing through the point $x_0$.

I'm interested in learning more about the extension referenced at the end of the article to the case where $X$ is an infinite-dimensional Hilbert manifold. Unfortunately, the article doesn't provide a reference for this. Does anyone know where I could find more information about this generalization?

Comment: I think the wiki page does a good job : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative . Essentially it is a derivative along a path in some direction - the notion of direction can of course be infinite dimensional.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but, unless I'm missing something, the wiki page doesn't appear to mention or give any references for Gateaux differentiability on Hilbert manifolds. This is the specific case that I'm looking for. But perhaps I'm missing something and wiki covers a more general case that yields the Hilbert manifold setting as a special case. If so, could you please clarify that?

Comment: If $f$ is a real-valued smooth function on a Hilbert Manifold $M$, then its tangent space at a point $p \in M$ is a hilbert space, $T_p(M)$.  Thus if you know how to define directional derivatives at a point in a manifold using the tangent (which is the "finite dimensional" Gateaux derivative) you can consider the same exercise, only this time the tangent space is infinite dimensional.  At least this is my interpretation.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. I'm still looking for a reference, though, so that I can get access to other results like the chain rule / etc., without having to reprove each from scratch. If any other readers know of such a reference, I'd really appreciate it if you'd point me towards it.

Comment: sure - what is your background? I assume you've taken courses in differential geometry/topology and functional analysis?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, that's right. I'm hoping for coverage along the lines of that in Berger's Nonlinearity and Functional Analysis, but for the case that the domain of the functional is a Hilbert manifold.